# Окно без вкладок для авторизации через социальные сети

Tags: php, html, html5, google-chrome

### Как называется такое окно в браузере?

[image: окно без вкладок]

Как выполнить запуск своей авторизации **в** таком **окне** **БЕЗ** **вкладок**
Обыскал весь интернет но не какой информации кроме как всплывающие окна на JS, CSS не нашел.
В данный момент на моем сайте авторизация происходит в том же окне то есть вот так:

[image: текущий способ авторизации]

Попытка **использовать** атрибут **target** **не** привела к **успех**у.
Будет хорошо если я получу информацию хотя бы о том как такое окно называется.

Comment: Хз как называется, но открывается через window.open в js

Comment: попап (popup window) - https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смею предложить нужно это:

```
window.open("https://oauth.vk.com/чета_там");
```

Answer (score 1):

Используя функцию в JavaScript
Передаёте url, имя окна и массив параметров
В параметры можно передавать и размер окна(ширину/высоту)
Подробнее про эту функцию можно прочитать здесь
https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods

```
window.open(url, name, params);
```